# Backbone Model not passing to view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am writing a new backbone application, and I am getting some errors on code that I have working in other applications.  I am using the newest version of backbone for this application, so I do not know if there have been changes that make what I am doing here break, or what.  Google has not been any help to me all day.

I have a collection that I am breaking apart, and sending the individual models to views.  The views report that this.model is undefined.

Code:

The view:

```
    DigitalAnalytics.View.TopPage = Backbone.Model.extend({
        tagName: 'tr',
        className: 'db-toppage-tr',
        template: DigitalAnalytics.Helper.template('db-analytics-toppages-template'),
        initialize: function() {
            console.log(this.model); // prints 'undefined'
        },
        render: function() {
            console.log(this.model); // prints 'undefined'

            // This throws an error saying that it can not call html() on undefined
            this.$el.html(this.template( this.model.toJSON()) );
            return this;
        },
        events: {}
    });
```

The collection view:

```
DigitalAnalytics.View.Collection.TopPages = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#db-analytics-toppages'),
    template: DigitalAnalytics.Helper.template(''),
    initialize: function() {
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render);  // Never fires even though the collection is returned
        this.collection.fetch(); // Works just fine
    },
    render: function() {
        this.collection.each( function(page, index) {
            console.log(page.toJSON()); // writes the object to console just fine 
            var topPage = new DigitalAnalytics.View.TopPage({model: page});
            this.$el.append( topPage.render().el );
        }, this);
    }
});
```

Comment: I haven't looked at your code to closely, but did you mean to extend from a view instead of a model (`DigitalAnalytics.View.TopPage = Backbone.Model.extend`)?

Comment: You should have extended View instead of a model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have extended `Backbone.Model` where you should have extended `Backbone.View`
Change `Backbone.Model.extend` in your code to `Backbone.View.extend`, create a Backbone model using `Backbone.Model` then pass this model to view when you initiate it.

Comment: winner winner.  I hate it when it is something super simple and obvious.  Thanks man.